# Received Weird/suspicious crash report form my Android app

Tags: android, crash, crash-reports, decompiling

Yesterday I received a Weird crash report from a device named "unknown Android Full Android on Emulator" running on Android 4.1.1 Whereas the minimum Android version required to run my android app is 5.0.

But the most surprising part is that the crash is from one of the class which is present in my App But currently is not being used by me in any part of the code

I tried googling about this but could not find anything useful.

Is it possible that someone might have tried to fiddle around with my app by decompiling it?

I Am new to Android development and this is my first app so any help would be really grateful.

Comment: "Is it possible that someone might have tried to fiddle around with my app by decompiling it?" -- yes.

Comment: @CommonsWare What are the precautions that can be taken to avoid these kind of situations in future?

Comment: If your concern is users running code that you are not using in the app yet, do not ship that code in your `release` build. If your concern is decompilation, don't create code that can be run by users. This includes mobile apps and Web apps (except those that involve no client-side JavaScript). Otherwise, by definition, users will run that code, and sometimes users will run that code in ways that you might not like.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there any precaution which can be taken now to stop the code from being misused?

Comment: The code is not being "misused". You decided to distribute your app. At that point, the "code" is theirs, not yours, and they can do whatever they want with that code. Obfuscating your code, using ProGuard or DexGuard, will reduce the number of developers who will take the time to "misuse" the code, but it will not eliminate it.

Comment: @CommonsWare " the "code" is theirs, not yours, and they can do whatever they want with that code"- My app has been uploaded to the play store and is not an open source app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144669/discussion-between-rahulrr2602-and-commonsware).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CommonsWare for that suggestion to Obfuscate the code, using ProGuard or DexGuard . I have Obfuscated the code. Hope it will reduce the number of developers who will reverse engineer the app.